# Why define PI = 4*ATAN(1.d0)

Tags: fortran, fortran77, pi

What is the motivation for defining PI as

```
PI=4.D0*DATAN(1.D0)
```

within Fortran 77 code?  I understand how it works, but, what is the reasoning?

Comment: As an alternative, I would almost expect to see PI = 3.1415926535... etc instead

Comment: I found a most excellent answer to the mathematics for this equation over on the Math Stackoverflow site http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211722/how-does-atan1-4-equal-pi

Comment: If you use PI = 3.1415926535... you must add the data type suffix to get anything other than default real precision.  Since you were using f66 double precision, that would be the D0 suffix.

Comment: Note: modern Fortran doesn't require `DATAN()`: `ATAN()` is aliased to its respective single- and double-precision versions, based on the argument.

Comment: "modern Fortran" you lost me there ;)

Comment: Modern Fortran is Fortran >= Fortran 2003

Comment: The feature mentioned here was introduced in Fortran 77.  For the last 30 years, the remaining situation where you would use datan is rather contrived and unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This style ensures that the maximum precision available on ANY architecture is used when assigning a value to PI.

Comment: But be warned if you follow this approach -- not all compilers and underlying maths libraries are equal in the results they return for trig functions of floating-point numbers, especially at critical points of those functions.  There has recently been a long discussion of this on comp.lang.fortran where most of the Fortran experts hang out.  Their conclusion -- specify the constant by pi = 3.14159...(enough digits for required precision then some for safety).

Comment: High Performance Mark: it would be nice if you could give a link to the comp.lang.fortran thread you mentioned!

Comment: Unfortunately, some languages go to great lengths to ensure that the value of pi returned by this approach is not the same value that is used in computing the period of trig functions.

Comment: @supercat: Any idea why? Or, can you cite it so I can ask it as a new question? :-)

Comment: @jvriesem: If someone tries to compute, e.g. sin(31416), the correct mathematical value should be sin(31416 minus (10000 times mathematical pi), and not sin(31416 - 10000 times the nearest floating-point value to mathematical pi).

Comment: @jvriesem: Personally, I doubt that there are very many situations where someone who calls e.g. sin(x) when x is outside the range +/-pi/2 would not be equally happy with the sine of any value whose closest representation is x.  Nonetheless, the Java language runtime adds extra code to its trig function implementations which, when asked to compute sin(x) for x near e.g. 2π will first subtract a precisely-representable value which is close to 2π and then subtract the difference between that value and mathematical 2π.

Comment: @jvriesem: If one imagines a floating-point system with five decimal digits of precision asked to compute sin(3.1416), it might (noting that π is about 3.1415 + 0.000092653 + 0.00000000058979), subtract 3.1415 from the value (yielding 0.0001), and then subtract 0.000092653 from that, yielding 0.000007347, and then subtract 0.00000000058979 from that, yielding 0.0000073464, of which it would then take the sine, yielding -0.0000073464.

Comment: @jvriesem: This result would be the five-digit value closest to the mathematical sine of the exact value 3.1416, but if 3.1416 is the result of a computation whose value, if computed perfectly without rounding, could have been anywhere between 3.14155 and 3.14165, then the perfectly-computed sine of a perfectly-computed value could be anywhere between -0.000057346 and 0.000042653, and any value in that range would be essentially as good as any other.

Answer (score 17):

Because Fortran does not have a built-in constant for `PI`. But rather than typing in the number manually and potentially making a mistake or not getting the maximum possible precision on the given implementation, letting the library calculate the result for you guarantees that neither of those downsides happen.

These are equivalent and you'll sometimes see them too:

```
PI=DACOS(-1.D0)
PI=2.D0*DASIN(1.D0)
```

Comment: Note that in Fortran 77 and later generic names ACOS and ASIN are preferred to the specific names DACOS and DASIN.

Answer (score 14):

I believe it's because this is the shortest series on pi. That also means it's the MOST ACCURATE.

The Gregory-Leibniz series (4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7...) equals pi.

atan(x) = x^1/1 - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7...

So, atan(1) = 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9...
4 * atan(1) = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9...

That equals the Gregory-Leibniz series, and therefore equals pi, approximately
3.1415926535 8979323846 2643383279 5028841971 69399373510.

Another way to use atan and find pi is:

pi = 16*atan(1/5) - 4*atan(1/239), but I think that's more complicated.

I hope this helps!

(To be honest, I think the Gregory-Leibniz series was based on atan, not 4*atan(1) based on the Gregory-Leibniz series. In other  words, the REAL proof is:

sin^2 x + cos^2 x = 1 [Theorem]
If x = pi/4 radians, sin^2 x = cos^2 x, or sin^2 x = cos^2 x = 1/2.

Then, sin x = cos x = 1/(root 2). tan x (sin x / cos x) = 1, atan x (1 / tan x) = 1.

So if atan(x) = 1, x = pi/4, and atan(1) = pi/4.
Finally, 4*atan(1) = pi.)

Please don't load me with comments-I'm still a pre-teen.

Comment: I dont understand how you get from atan x (1/tan x) = 1 to atan(x) = 1

Comment: remark that with the formula `pi = 16*atan(1/5) - 4*atan(1/239)` is numerically not a good choice. Both `1/5` and `1/239` cannot be represented accurately using floating-point numbers. Hence, the atan will already introduce errors due to these floating-point approximations.

Answer (score 11):

There is more to this question than meets the eye. Why `4 arctan(1)`? Why not any other representation such as `3 arccos(1/2)`?

This will try to find an answer by exclusion.

**Mathematical intro:** When using *inverse trigonometric functions* such as *arccos, arcsin* and *arctan*, one can easily compute π in various ways:

```
π = 4 arctan(1) = arccos(-1) = 2 arcsin(1) = 3 arccos(1/2) = 6 arcsin(1/2)
  = 3 arcsin(sqrt(3)/2) = 4 arcsin(sqrt(2)/2) = ...
```

There exist many other [exact algebraic expressions for trigonometric values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) that could be used here.

**Floating-point argument 1:** it is well understood that a *finite binary floating-point representation* cannot represent **all** real numbers. Some examples of such numbers are `1/3, 0.97, π, sqrt(2), ...`. To this end, we should **exclude** any mathematical computation of π where the argument to the inverse trigonometric functions cannot be represented numerically. This leaves us the arguments `-1,-1/2,0,1/2` and `1`.

```
π = 4 arctan(1) = 2 arcsin(1)
   = 3 arccos(1/2) = 6 arcsin(1/2)
   = 2 arccos(0)
   = 3/2 arccos(-1/2) = -6 arcsin(-1/2)
   = -4 arctan(-1) = arccos(-1) = -2 arcsin(-1)
```

**Floating-point argument 2:** in the binary representation, a number is represented as *0.b<sub>n</sub>b<sub>n-1</sub>...b<sub>0</sub> x 2<sup>m</sup>*. If the inverse trigonometric function came up with the best numeric binary approximation for its argument, we do not want to lose precision by multiplication. To this end we should only multiply with powers of 2.

```
π = 4 arctan(1) = 2 arcsin(1)
  = 2 arccos(0)
  = -4 arctan(-1) = arccos(-1) = -2 arcsin(-1)
```

*Note:* this is visible in the [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representation (the most common form of `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `kind=REAL64`). There we have

```
write(*,'(F26.20)') 4.0d0*atan(1.0d0) -> "    3.14159265358979311600"
write(*,'(F26.20)') 3.0d0*acos(0.5d0) -> "    3.14159265358979356009"
```

This difference is not there in [IEEE-754 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (the most common form of `REAL` or `kind=REAL32`) and [IEEE-754 binary128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) (the most common form of `kind=REAL128`)

**Implementation argument:** On intel CPU, the `atan2` is part of the [x86 Instruction set as `FPATAN`](https://x86.puri.sm/html/file_module_x86_id_106.html) while the other inverse trigonometric function are derived from `atan2`. A potential derivation could be:

```
          mathematically         numerically
ACOS(x) = ATAN2(SQRT(1-x*x),1) = ATAN2(SQRT((1+x)*(1-x)),1)
ASIN(x) = ATAN2(1,SQRT(1-x*x)) = ATAN2(1,SQRT((1+x)*(1-x)))
```

This can be seen in the assembly code of these instructions (See [here](https://davidwong.fr/goasm/arcsin)). To this end I would argue the usage of:

```
π = 4 arctan(1)
```

*Note:* this is a fuzzy argument. I'm certain there are people with better opinions on this.
*Interesting reads on `FPATAN`:* [How is arctan implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23047978/8344060), [x87 trigonometric instructions](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14244)

**The Fortran argument:** why should we approximate `π` as :

```
integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6, 37)
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(33, 4931)

real(kind=sp), parameter :: pi_sp = 4.0_sp*atan2(1.0_sp,1.0_sp)
real(kind=dp), parameter :: pi_dp = 4.0_dp*atan2(1.0_dp,1.0_dp)
real(kind=qp), parameter :: pi_qp = 4.0_qp*atan2(1.0_qp,1.0_qp)
```

and not :

```
real(kind=sp), parameter :: pi_sp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_sp
real(kind=dp), parameter :: pi_dp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_dp
real(kind=qp), parameter :: pi_qp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_qp
```

The answer lays in the [Fortran standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf). The standard **never** states that a `REAL` of any kind should represent an [IEEE-754 floating point number](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935). The representation of `REAL` is processor dependent. This implies that I could inquire `selected_real_kind(33, 4931)` and expect to obtain a [binary128 floating-point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format), but I might get a `kind` returned that represents a floating-point with much higher accuracy. Maybe 100 digits, who knows. In this case, my above string of numbers is to short! One cannot use [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/data/pi-10million.txt) just to be sure? Even that file could be too short!

**Interesting fact : `sin(pi) is never zero`**

```
write(*,'(F17.11)') sin(pi_sp) => "   -0.00000008742"
write(*,'(F26.20)') sin(pi_dp) => "    0.00000000000000012246"
write(*,'(F44.38)') sin(pi_qp) => "    0.00000000000000000000000000000000008672"
```

which is understood as:

```
pi = 4 ATAN2(1,1) = π + δ
SIN(pi) = SIN(pi - π) = SIN(δ) ≈ δ
```

---

```
program print_pi
! use iso_fortran_env, sp=>real32, dp=>real64, qp=>real128

  integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6, 37)
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(33, 4931)

  real(kind=sp), parameter :: pi_sp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_sp
  real(kind=dp), parameter :: pi_dp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_dp
  real(kind=qp), parameter :: pi_qp = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288_qp
  
  write(*,'("SP "A17)') "3.14159265358..."
  write(*,'(F17.11)') pi_sp
  write(*,'(F17.11)')        acos(-1.0_sp)
  write(*,'(F17.11)') 2.0_sp*asin( 1.0_sp)
  write(*,'(F17.11)') 4.0_sp*atan2(1.0_sp,1.0_sp)
  write(*,'(F17.11)') 3.0_sp*acos(0.5_sp)
  write(*,'(F17.11)') 6.0_sp*asin(0.5_sp)

  write(*,'("DP "A26)') "3.14159265358979323846..."
  write(*,'(F26.20)') pi_dp
  write(*,'(F26.20)')        acos(-1.0_dp)
  write(*,'(F26.20)') 2.0_dp*asin( 1.0_dp)
  write(*,'(F26.20)') 4.0_dp*atan2(1.0_dp,1.0_dp)
  write(*,'(F26.20)') 3.0_dp*acos(0.5_dp)
  write(*,'(F26.20)') 6.0_dp*asin(0.5_dp)

  write(*,'("QP "A44)') "3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419..."
  write(*,'(F44.38)') pi_qp
  write(*,'(F44.38)')        acos(-1.0_qp)
  write(*,'(F44.38)') 2.0_qp*asin( 1.0_qp)
  write(*,'(F44.38)') 4.0_qp*atan2(1.0_qp,1.0_qp)
  write(*,'(F44.38)') 3.0_qp*acos(0.5_qp)
  write(*,'(F44.38)') 6.0_qp*asin(0.5_qp)

  write(*,'(F17.11)') sin(pi_sp)
  write(*,'(F26.20)') sin(pi_dp)
  write(*,'(F44.38)') sin(pi_qp)

end program print_pi
```

Comment: Along with the argument sin(pi) /= 0 I have always been reluctant to assume that acos(-1d0) would be as accurate as 4*atan(1d0), although it may be, depending on the implementation.

Comment: I believe there is a proven algorithm for sin() to produce a correctly rounded value for large arguments, although it comes with considerable additional execution time.  I haven't seen the reference.  Some IBM libraries gave you this by default.  Any high quality implementation will involve some simulation of extra precision which avoids significant degradation of accuracy up to arguments as large as could be useful in practice, say +-20 Pi, or the (smaller) point at which the internal m387 implementation changes abruptly from returning an accurate value to returning the argument.

Comment: By the way, the internal Pi constant in the m387 firmware is advertised as carrying 66 bits precision.  Actually, this is nothing special in the implementation; the correctly rounded 66 bit precision value has 2 low order zero bits.  A high quality C compiler will give you this value for a long double constant with 21 digits.

Answer (score 9):

It's because this is an exact way to compute `pi` to arbitrary precision. You can simply continue executing the function to get greater and greater precision and stop at any point to have an approximation.

By contrast, specifying `pi` as a constant provides you with exactly as much precision as was originally given, which may not be appropriate for highly scientific or mathematical applications (as Fortran is frequently used with).

Answer (score -8):

That sounds an awful lot like a work-around for a compiler bug.  Or it could be that this particular program depends on that identity being exact, and so the programmer made it guaranteed.

Comment: It's actually a very common way of setting the value of PI -- not only in Fortran, but in other languages as well. 

(See above comments.)