# Why is System.Math.PI in all caps (or a public field)?

Tags: .net, notation, capitalization

In .Net 4.5, System.Math.PI is written as such, in all caps. Microsoft's own [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) state that Pascal casing is to be used for all public members. Also, their conventions on [Names of Type Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012(v=vs.110).aspx) mention that all public static fields (which PI is, considering that it's a const) should use Pascal casing.

I'm aware that there's sometimes a convention to name constants in all caps, but the capitalization conventions mention nothing about constants. Pi is also not an acronym like IO, so shouldn't it just be System.Math.Pi?

Comment: And it is not even an abbreviation (like ID = identifier) :-)

Comment: If they'd been brave, they'd have named it `Math.π`. So maybe because it's real name is only a single letter, it is in pascal case, as much as one letter can be :-)

Comment: My money's on it being a mistake in the early framework versions, and although fixing it would be trivial, it would be a huge breaking change to client code with no real benefit, so it stays as it is.

Comment: There are other similar errors, like the `RSA` class (all upper-case).

Comment: If we consider `PI` to be the Asciization of `π`, then being `π` uppercase, the whole `PI` should be uppercase (ok, I know, it is stupid :-), as we say in italy, it is an "arrampicarsi sugli specchi", "clutching at straws" for english-speaking persons)

Comment: More famous errors: the whole `Encoding.*` static properties: `ASCII`, `UTF7`, `UTF8`, `UTF32`

Comment: @xanatos And that's even besides the fact that two letter abbreviations should _also_ only capitalize the first letter. :)

Comment: Not so sure if this is a shocker, but PI was used long before .NET came around :)  Very often capitalized, they just didn't break with the common convention.  Like [Cobol](http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#what-is-pi-in-opencobol), [Fortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157920/why-define-pi-4atan1), [C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912151/math-constant-pi-value-in-c), etc.  Pascal was a notable exception.

Comment: @HansPassant At least two examples are bad: in C it was "correct" to be all-upper because it was a constant. Older fortran were all upper in general... On Cobol I can't speak (but being very old, I wouldn't be surprised if it was an all-upper language)

Comment: @Bas: Certain two letter abbreviations are generally written entirely in uppercase or lowercase; ID comes to mind.  I think someone likely decided that `.Pi` looked weird, and that `.PI` looked better.